# iw dev wlan0 station dump output signal missing

Tags: pi-4

I used the following command

> iw dev wlan0 station dump

to collect the information about the devices connected to the AP. I used to see ***signal level*** in the output in Raspberry Pi 3. When I tried to do same thing in Raspberry PI 4 (recently upgraded), I can see all information except ***signal level***. Could you please help me how to see signal information using the command in Raspberry Pi 4.
Rajan
[image]

Comment: do you mean ***signal***? there is no ***signal level*** even in Pi 3

Comment: yes signal- dBm value

Comment: that's odd then - because it's definitely showing `signal` in the output for all pi 3's 3+'s and 4's

Comment: Please look the output from the command. signal is missing. Any ideas?

Comment: what's the output of `iw --version`

Comment: hang on ... what is `wlan1`? the pi4 has `wlan0` not `wlan1`

Comment: I am using two WLAN

Comment: I am using two WLANs. One is using in-built raspberry pi and another using USB (TP link one). I do not have any problem with TP link one. In-built Raspberry pi WLN is wlan1 and TP link one is wlan0. Version for iw version is 5.0.1. Any ideas?

Comment: are you sure you have that the right way around? try disconnecting the tp-link device

Comment: Yep, it is correct. I have checked it multiple times. The result is still same.

Comment: so, when you disconnect the tp-link device, the built in wlan is still wlan1 ... and you still can't see `signal`

Comment: When TP link device is removed, it will be wlan0.

Comment: and still doesn't show signal - odd - works fine on all my pi4's